# How to compile or get mod_heartbeat for apache2?

Tags: linux, apache

I'm using `apache httpd` on SUSE 12.2 and want to enable `mod_heartbeat`. However it does't seem to have `mod_heartbeat` module file in any of the module directories. When I try to enable the module I get an error that the module cannot be found.

I installed apache via `zypper install apache2` which installs version 2.2.2 but doesn't include the module. I also tried to search for additional mods using `zypper search apache` but didn't find the heartbeat mod there either.
Finally I downloaded the sources for apache 2.4 and compiled them. I didn't get any compile errors and the files were compiled to `/usr/local/apache2`. The Directory `/usr/local/apache2/modules` contains several mods but no mod_heartbeat.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or how I can compile or obtain the missing module file?

Comment: Never mind I figured it out. The source needs to be explicitly cofigured to build that module using 'httpd-2.4.7/configure --enable-watchdog=shared  --enable-heartbeat=shared'. Then 'make' and 'make install'.

Answer (score 0):

The source for several modules including mod_heartbeat can be obtained at https://github.com/omnigroup/Apache/tree/master/httpd/modules/cluster